# Remove "Cc: " from mailx command

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, sendmail, terminal, command

I have recently setup a mail server on my Ubuntu Desktop 16.10, and I made a script that when a specific user logs in, they will execute the script instead of bash. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
    echo -n "To: "
    read To
    echo -n "Subject: "
    read Subject
    echo -n "Attachments [y/N]: "
    read AttachYN
    if [[ $AttachYN == "" || $AttachYN == "n" || $AttachYN == "N" ]]
    then
        mail "$To" -s "$Subject"
        exit
    elif [[ $AttachYN == "y" || $AttachYN == "Y"  ]]
    then
        echo -n "File path: "
        read File
        mail "$To" -s "$Subject" -A "$file"
        exit
    else
        echo "Incorrect character, must be y, Y, n, N, or blank for default [n]"
    fi
done
```

Upon execution, it asks for `Cc:` input, but I don't want this, as I don't use `Cc`.

How do I remove this?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't get prompted for `Cc:` if `echo "foobar"` gets executed successfully. What is the exact command you're using?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: prepending your mail command with `echo ""` would solve this.

Comment: I doesn't allow for space for the body now :/

Answer (score 2):

Change the command sending the email like this:

```
mail "$To" -s "$Subject" < /dev/null
```

It will do it for you. If you later decide that you need a `Cc:` recipient, simply add it with `-c` switch to the `mail` command. You can read it from a command prompt, like you do  with the recipient and the subject.

Comment: `mail: Null message body; hope that's ok`

Comment: Yes. It means that you have nothing in the `body` of the email - which is true. The valuable information you sent with this email is the subject, together with an attachment (if present).

Comment: `mail "$To" -s "$Subject"` asks for the body anyway (As well as the Cc), after it has been executed.

Comment: Did you add `< /dev/null` at the end of both `mail` commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can change this by setting the `askcc` option to `False`.

```
echo "set askcc=False;" >> ~/.mailrc
```

This will append the option to the .mailrc file in your homedirectory. If no config file exists it will be created.

If you run the command under a different user, for example under cron, you will have to set this for the user that runs the command.